# Telnet script does not work inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, telnetlib

Out of function, the script works, but inside the function, script does not work.

```
import telnetlib
import sys

def teltest():

    host = "192.168.2.2"
    user = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    tn.read_until("Username:")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password:")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.write("enable\n")
    tn.write("config t\n")
    tn.write("interface eth 0/0/13\n")
    tn.write("description TEST\n")

teltest()
```

Why and how can i fix it?

Comment: what do you mean it "does not work"?

Comment: The changes are not applied to the switch.

Comment: Possibly a timing difference - in a function, the connection is going to be closed instantly at the end of the function (when `tn` goes out of scope and gets garbage collected); outside of a function, the connection might hang around indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, it works for me! i added time.sleep(1) to the end of the script inside the function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the function returns before properly terminating the connection leaving the other end of the device in a meta state. Adding a sleep at the end as mentioned in the comments would let room for cleaning up the connection thereby executing what was written onto the device.

> Telnet.write(buffer) Write a string to the socket, doubling any IAC
>   characters. This can block if the connection is blocked. May raise
>   socket.error if the connection is closed.

```
import telnetlib
import sys

def teltest():
    host = "192.168.2.2"
    user = "admin"
    password = "admin"
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    tn.read_until("Username:")
    tn.write(user + "\n")
    tn.read_until("Password:")
    tn.write(password + "\n")
    tn.write("enable\n")
    tn.write("config t\n")
    tn.write("interface eth 0/0/13\n")
    tn.write("description TEST\n")
    time.sleep(1)

teltest()
```

Posting this as an answer for the benefit of the community despite the fact that the op received help from comments.